# User wants to remove a value, but the value isn't on the Binary Tree. How to treat it?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary-tree

I have this code in C for removing nodes or leafs from a Binary Tree, where 'elemento' is a value entered by a user and raiz is my tree.

My problem is: I don't know what to do if user enters a number (elemento) which is not in the tree. I tried some ways, but nothing worked. I want it to print something when the value isn't found.

Here's the function code:

```
void removerNo(no **raiz, int elemento)
{
 if(elemento < (*raiz)->valor){
    removerNo(&(*raiz)->esq,elemento);
 }
 else if(elemento > (*raiz)->valor){
    removerNo(&(*raiz)->dir,elemento);
 }
 else if((*raiz)->esq!=NULL && (*raiz)->dir!=NULL){
    no *aux = NULL;
    aux = DoisFilhos((*raiz)->dir);
    (*raiz)->valor = aux->valor;
    removerNo(&(*raiz)->dir,(*raiz)->valor);
 } else{
    no *aux = (*raiz);
    if((*raiz)->esq==NULL){
        (*raiz) = (*raiz)->dir;
    }
    else{
         *raiz = (*raiz)->esq;
    }
    free(aux);
 }
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if the element does not equal the current node's value and the current node's relevant child is NULL, the element doesn't exist. e.g.

```
if ((elemento > (*raiz)->valor && (*raiz)->dir == NULL) || ((elemento < (*raiz)->valor && (*raiz)->esq == NULL)){
    printf("Element not found.");
    return;
}
```

I would recommend returning a value from removeNo that can represent success/failure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code statements assume that if your not less than and not greater than, that you are equal ( and thus present) in a tree.  You should, after finding out your not less than or greater than, check for !null and also that the element exists.

If either the null check is true, or the element exists, you then do something to indicate failure due to the tree being traversed but the value not being present.